# C++ - Using strcpy_s(s+2,s+3); doesn't work - "function does not take 2 arguments"

Tags: c++

I just started to learn about char and its functions and I'm trying to copy it like that.

My teacher in class gave us this example:

For s = "carte", strcpy(s+2, s+3) => s="cate". Obviously I wanted to try it out, but I'm getting this error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2660   'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments
"

Tips?
Thanks.

Comment: Your example shows the use of `strcpy`, while the error message says that you are using `strcpy_s`, so which one, are you using, really? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: your teacher gave you a *bad example* and should be shot for it.  here is what you tell him/her: The memory source and destination overlap and that he/she is assuming that strcpy will use memmove (which safely does the copy) where as that's not what happens in real life.  EDIT: @AlgirdasPreidžius caught the reference to `strcpy_s` in the error! If the teacher used that then there would be a size parameter: Even then *The behavior of strcpy_s is undefined if the source and destination strings overlap*

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius nice catch on the strcpy_s my comment assumed strcpy and I think the teacher is being pedantic on the board

Comment: You can't use `strcpy` if the destination and the source overlap.

Comment: I tried using strcpy and I'm getting an error from Visual Studio, and I changed it to strcpy_s after reading that it should be used.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. @AhmedMasud

Comment: I didn't know strcpy_s used 3 parameters.... it worked with something like strcpy_s(s,t) and I thought it is just the same as strcpy(s,t). So what should I do? Is my teacher wrong?

Comment: Even when you use strcpy_s the destination memory buffer (s+2) cannot overlap with source, in your case (s+3), your teacher it's giving you a bad example of using strcpy_s

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is the OP's example really an overlap? I would have expected `strcpy(s+3, s+2)`  being an overlap. Why wouldn't standard just say, if the source and destination belong to the same string instead? But it talks about actual overlap.

Comment: @AhmedMasud he didn't say anthing about strcpy_s as I said above. "I tried using strcpy and I'm getting an error from Visual Studio, and I changed it to strcpy_s after reading that it should be used." he talked only about strcpy, but I can't use that. (see above)

Comment: @KillzoneKid If parts of the buffer you are writing to is shared with parts of the buffer you are reading from, it's an overlap.

Comment: in either case, whether it's `strcpy` or `strcpy_s` his example is bad!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but with `strcpy(s+2, s+3)` you are reading from s+3 and writing to s+2, then from s+4 to s+3 and so on. Why would this produce undefined behaviour?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Because `strcpy` doesn't define it's behavior in case of overlap. That's it. In practice, it's for example possible for `strcpy` to copy by chunks of `sizeof(int)` or something for performance reasons. In any case, whether or not you and I can come up with a case where it break it's still undefined behavior. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) : *"The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap."*  Notice there are no conditions mentioned. It's always undefined in case of overlap.

Comment: @AhmedMasud can you explain me why? So: s = "carte", strcpy(s+2, s+3) => s="cate". If I'm using strcpy it does work as he said, but Visual Studio gives me an error by default when I use strcpy so I have to use strcpy_s(s+2, s+3). At that point I'm getting this: ""Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C2660 'strcpy_s': function does not take 2 arguments".

Comment: @KillzoneKid from the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy): *"strcpy_s is allowed to clobber the destination array from the last character written up to destsz in order to improve efficiency: it may copy in multibyte blocks and then check for null bytes."*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, fair enough and thanks

Comment: Visual studio should only give you a *warning* not an error when using strcpy (which you can ignore)

Comment: @Bob__ Splendid, this answers it, thank you!

Comment: @AhmedMasud it doesn't compile. It's an error. Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy_s` takes 3 parameters. Note the `_s` suffix for "secure". Make sure you provide the correct size of the destination buffer to make it work as this function checks for buffer overflow (thus the "secure" suffix).

For reference: here's the [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) for the function on cppreference

Comment: It actually works with strcpy_s(s, t) too. (without the 3rd one)

Comment: @f0rta Only if `s` is an actual array and not a pointer, then its size can be deduced by the template